# High Anr in android 8.0 and 8.1 due to this

Tags: android

Broadcast of Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x11000010 pkg=com.printvenue.android cmp=com.printvenue.android/com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver (has extras) }  com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver

Comment: Did you fix this ANR?